# Default Value for Collection in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5.1

I have three tables: `test_main` (could be empty on start), `test_sec` (almost always has records) and binding table `test_ref`(storess unique id combinations of records from `test_main` and `test_sec`).

I need to create a package with procedures that deal with inserions and updates of records in `test_main` and `test_ref`. I need some help with it.

Here's the code of a package:

```
create or replace package TEST_PKG is 
  type t_num is table of number;
  procedure ADD (arg_main_id number
                 , arg_name varchar2
                 , arg_sec_ids t_num);
end test_pkg;

create or replace package body test_pkg is 
  procedure ADD (arg_main_id number
                 , arg_name varchar2
                 , arg_sec_ids t_num)
  is begin
    insert into test_main (id, col_name) 
    values (arg_main_id, arg_name);
    commit;
    for i in arg_sec_ids.first .. arg_sec_ids.last loop
      insert into test_ref (main_id, sec_id) 
      values (arg_main_id, arg_sec_ids(i));
    end loop;
    commit;
  end ADD;
end test_pkg;
```

I plan to call this procedure in Oracle APEX 5.1 PL/SQL Dynamic Action as follows:

```
declare
  selection apex_t_number 
  -- or "test_pkg.t_num" with values from "apex_string.split_numbers" added through a "for" loop later
begin
  selection := apex_string.split_numbers(:P1_SELECT2,':');
  -- for example, '1:2:3' string results in a [1,2,3] array
  ADD (arg_main_id => :P1_MAIN_ID
       , arg_name => :P1_MAIN_NAME
       , arg_sec_ids => selection);
end;
```

But I also would like to be able to call it as `ADD (arg_main_id => :P1_MAIN_ID, arg_name => :P1_MAIN_NAME)` with a default value for `arg_sec_ids`.
So, is it possible to define default value for a collection in PL/SQL Procedure, and if so, how to?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `arg_sec_ids` parameter as of `in out` style is of type `t_num`.

```
create or replace package test_pkg is
    type t_num is table of number;
    procedure add (
                   arg_main_id number, 
                   arg_name    varchar2,
                   arg_sec_ids in out t_num 
                   );                   
end;
```

and suppose to initialize with `arg_sec_ids := t_num(1,1,2,3,5,8);` in the program body, and if you extend with an integer with value number of elements in the tuple, you can use the next values for `arg_sec_ids` such as `arg_sec_ids(7),..,arg_sec_ids(10)`.

```
create or replace package body test_pkg is
procedure add (
               arg_main_id number, 
               arg_name    varchar2,
               arg_sec_ids in out t_num 
               ) is
begin

  arg_sec_ids := t_num(1,1,2,3,5,8);
  arg_sec_ids.extend(10);
  insert into test_main (id, col_name)
  values (arg_main_id, arg_name);

  for i in arg_sec_ids.first .. arg_sec_ids.last loop
      insert into test_ref (main_id, sec_id)
      values (arg_main_id, arg_sec_ids(i));
  end loop;
      arg_sec_ids(7) := arg_sec_ids(5)+ arg_sec_ids(6);
      dbms_output.put_line( ' arg_sec_ids(7)''s values is : '||arg_sec_ids(7) );
  commit;
end add;
end;
```

If `arg_sec_ids.extend(x)` is omitted (where x>6 ), it's impossible to use arrays with index more than default length( which's `6` in this case ).